# Use data from a drop down list to populate table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, pivot-table

I am trying to make an employee recognition tracking tool. I would like to have in sheet 1 a drop down list of all the employees in the hotel and a drop down list of the month.

When an employee receives a recognition card you can go to sheet one, pick their name from the drop down list and pick the the month the card was received in from another drop down list.

I want a button that says enter or input or something that then creates a table on sheet two that keeps track of how many times an employee receives a card during that month.

I have my two drop down lists created, I just dont know how to get the data to record into a table.

Comment: Just a suggestion - don't use a spreadsheet to do a database's job

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is a data entry FORM for a data table (or database). Excel does not do this out of the box. You would need to create a form with VBA and a lot of user interface handling code to create a smooth user interface for this in Excel.

You basically have two options:

1. Forget Excel and create the solution in a database application like Access, where creating the form and the storage database will be a snap for someone familiar with the software.
2. pay less attention to a data entry form and simply use an Excel table. Each new data entry will happen in a new row of a table. Data validation (drop-down lists) can be set up to automatically show in every new row of a table. Instead of using a form to enter the data, you use the Excel interface and enter the new data into a new row in the table.

Option 2 means that you can continue to use Excel, which you may be more familiar with, compared to a database like Access. If you want to explore VBA and the possibilities of creating and configuring a form as the user interface, that is also possible, but will require a bit of engagement beyond the out-of-the-box Excel experience.

Your choice.